# How to whitelist 2 ip-adresses with ip-tables and block everything else?

Tags: mysql, networking, database-connection, firewall, iptables

I want to whitelist 2 external ip-adresses vor port 3306 (mysql), but block all other IP-adresses to the port 3306 on a debian server running a mysql-instance. Both external ip-adresses should be able to connect to the mysql-server.

What is the best way in iptables?

**What i did:**

> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
>
> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
>
> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 85.x.x.x --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

(1.1.1.1 is an internal ip and masked here for security purposes)

> ## Block all connections to 3306 ##
>
> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP

**What happened:**

every external ip is locked and can't connect

**What should happen:**

every external ip will be locked cand can't connect but not 1.1.1.1 and 85.x.x.x and 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iptables -N mysql  # create chain for mysql
iptables -A mysql --src 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mysql --src 1.1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mysql --src 85.x.x.x -j ACCEPT
iptables -A mysql -j DROP  # drop packets from other hosts
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j mysql  # use chain for packets to MySQL port